# Encoding Data NSString with Mail

Tags: email, encoding, character-encoding, nsdata, mailcore

I'm trying to send some data (NSDictionaray) with Mailcore.
However the body is either null or ""
My code is :
*

```
// Dic is  NSDictionary
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc]initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
[archiver encodeObject:dic forKey:@"k"];
[archiver finishEncoding];
[archiver release];
NSString *value = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
CTCoreMessage *msg = [[CTCoreMessage alloc]initWithString:value];
```

Here value is : bplist00Ô¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿bcT$topX$objectsX$versionY$archiver¿¿¿Ñ¿¿¿Qk�¯

&'(/>?@AELMRWX]U$nullÓ
 ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿ZNS.objectsWNS.keysV$class¡�¡��WrequestÙ
 !"#$%YrequestIDYoperationQaQrXpeerNameQfVpeerIDQv���¿¿¿¿¿¿¿

But the msg.body is : ""

If I try with :

```
NSString *value = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Value will be null, so the message body too.
Shall I try a different encoding ?